Interpretation of this result on quadratic polynomials
Let $f(x,y) = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$. We have
$$ f(-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}) = - (B^2 - 4AC) \cdot f(x,y). $$
It's trivial to plug in and verify. I just wonder if there's any way to interpret it nicely, say via quadratic form or symplectic form.

Have you tried Gaussian curvature or characteristic surface?
